# shared_id/~username is showing 404

Tags: linux, ip, apache2, cpanel

when I'm trying to access my site it works fine with http://domain_name/ but when I'm trying to use it with http://ip/~username it goes to 404 page.

Do I need to do some additional settings in WHM or in cPanel or activate something ?

Is there any reason for it. Please let me know

I think something might related with mod_userdir but when I'm visiting that page in WHM it shows this :

> Web server processes on this system currently run as the user. For
>   security reasons, the system disabled mod_userdir. Any changes that
>   you make in this interface will not take effect until you enable
>   mod_userdir. To use mod_userdir, you must disable mod_ruid2, mod_itk,
>   and mod_passenger and recompile EasyApache.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need use Apache Module mod_userdir and configure [Per-user web directories](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/public_html.html) for your default virtual host to enable the `/~username/` URLs.

> On systems with multiple users, each user can be permitted to have a
>   web site in their home directory using the [`UserDir`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_userdir.html#userdir) directive.
>   Visitors to a URL `http://example.com/~username/` will get content out
>   of the home directory of the user "username", out of the subdirectory
>   specified by the `UserDir` directive.
>
> Note that, by default, access to these directories is **not** enabled.

Is there any reason for it? Not unless you provide websites for your users not having an own domain name. For *search engine optimization* it's better to have a single canonical address for your site.

Comment: Its saying : Web server processes on this system currently run as the user. For security reasons, the system disabled mod_userdir. Any changes that you make in this interface will not take effect until you enable mod_userdir. To use mod_userdir, you must disable mod_ruid2, mod_itk, and mod_passenger and recompile EasyApache.

Comment: It's saying... already everything you need to know. One reason less to worry about something you don't actually need.

Comment: So for running with http://ip/~username should I disable mod_ruid2 and enable mod_userdir or there's any other way to directly run it with mod_ruid2 enabled ?

Comment: They are not alternatives but for totally different purposes. Mod_ruid2 is a suexec module. Why you think you should have an `/~username` URL in the first place?

Comment: because I don't wanna share domain till development is going I need to access via ip

Comment: Use some `development.example.com` sub domain instead.